# Could not find a declaration file for module 'styled-components'

Tags: reactjs, frontend, styled-components

im having this error when trying to create a global style using styled components v5.3.5. Can you guys help me here please?

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    :root {
        --background: #f0f2f5;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background-color: var(--background);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiesed;
    }
`;
```

Comment: Have you installed `styled-components` package?

Comment: yes, i have installed the 5.3.5 version

Comment: can you paste the error message here

Comment: i installed the  @types/styled-components and the error was gone. Sorry for taking your time with such a trivial thing.

Answer (score 0):

This error should be resolved with
`npm i -D @types/styled-components@latest`